# how can i register Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0?

Tags: c#

I can not connect with access
when I try the message which I receive that " Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 " not registered , what I can do? if there is thing to develop give me link please.

Comment: You need to install MDAC. See : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1d5c04c7-157f-4955-a14b-41d912d50a64/how-to-fix-error-quotthe-microsoftaceoledb120-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local?forum=vstsdb

Comment: Ace comes with Microsoft Office. If the PC has Microsoft Office installed then the version install is not matching.  Version 12 is Office 2008.  So check version in following folder : C:\Program Files\Common Files\system\ado.  If office is not installed then you have to install the ACE manually.  I've never been successful at doing this but others have.